# opencv line size of drew contour

Tags: ios, opencv, drawing, contour

I would like to draw contours thicker on an image on iOS, but I could not see any option in function `cv::drawContours(<#InputOutputArray image#>, <#InputArrayOfArrays contours#>, <#int      contourIdx#>, <#const Scalar &color#>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just did not [see the next argument to drawContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours), there is 'thickness' . if you set it to -1, your contour will get filled even.

Comment: In function list it only shows first four arguments, I forget to look actual prototype. Thanks..